# White space on top of UITableView after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scrollview

I am using a tableView to show some data. On top of tableView I have searchBar that I have it to search within the data and present them in the same tableView.

Everything works fine except a very weird case.

The following steps make the issue of having a gap on top of first row on the tableView

Tap on 1)SearchBar , 2) Scroll just a bit , 3) Start writing the name in searchBar.

In some cases depending that letters you write it comes the issue faster of slower.

Example. Searching a name Erik

1. SearchBar text -> "E" brings some rows
2. SearchBar text -> "Er" brings some rows
3. SearchBar text -> "Eri" brings one row with a gap on top (same height as a tableView Row)
4. SearchBar text -> "Erik" bring one row and disappear the gap on the top

That's how I reproduce the issue. It is apparently a scroll issue.

[image: issue]

Apparently is not part of constraints because the backboard of the tableView is coloured and attach to the correct place.

By tapping in the tableView everything comes in order.

I reload() everything.

Any Idea with similar issue?

Comment: If your `TableView` is not the first child of its parent View, try move it forward to become the first child.

Comment: What about the content insets for the tableView. If you add the tableview as the first view in the hierarchy, you might have the "adjust scroll insets" enabled.

Comment: Can you provide some example of how I can implement that ?